# Dynamic pipe model in Modelica Standard Library

Tags: pipe, transfer, modelica, heat

The Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe model looks very convenient. It is like an "all in one" model. But I don't see any info about the convection heat transfer between the pipe and the fluid inside.

Is the model taking heat convection into account?

I am trying to model a heat exchanger made by a bundle of pipes. That's why it is important to incorporate the convection from both sides of the pipe.

Is it a better idea to use the Modelica.Thermal.Components.ThermalConductor model with combination with two convection models?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DynamicPipe` offers three different models for convective heat transfer. You select which one to use on the second parameter tab `Assumption` with the dropdown parameter `HeatTransfer`. (`use_HeatTransfer` must be set to true).

The models are the following:

`IdealHeatTransfer`: the temperature(s) on the heat_port is equal to the bulk temperature(s) in the fluid, i.e. no convective heat transfer in the fluid.

`ConstantHeatTransfer`: The temperature(s) on the heat_port are given by the relation `Q_flow = h*A(heat_port.T - fluid.T)` where the convective heat transfer coefficient `h` is constant (set `h` by clicking on the table icon next to the drop down).

`LocalPipeFlowHeatTransfer`: same relation as above, but is flow dependent. h is calucated as a function of geometry and fluid properties, i.e. h=f(Re,Pr)

You could choose to implement you own heat transfer correlation, by writing a model that extends from `PartialHeatTransfer` or `PartialFlowHeatTransfer`.

Regards,
Rene Just Nielsen

Note: If you need a model of the wall separating the two fluids in you heat exchanger, you could use `Modelica.Fluid.Examples.HeatExchanger.BaseClasses.WallConstProps`

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very helpful.